# Auto generating dates based on a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL server

[image]

And I want to generate each presentation day between StartDate and EndDate. Normally, I have to create a script, declare a cursor and loop through the cursor to create each individual date. But using cursor slows thing down considerably.

I wonder if anyone has a better idea using join

I am successful in generating date based on a startdate and enddate

```
SELECT d."CalendarDay"                     AS "PresenttionDate",
   DATEPART(dw,d."CalendarDay")            AS "PresentationDay"
FROM
   (
     SELECT StartDate-1+number AS "CalendarDay"
     FROM master..spt_values
     where type='P' and number<= DateDiff(day,StartDate,EndDate) 
   )d
```

I just do not know how to tie the StartDate and EndDate to the presentation table.

Basically, I am looking for the end results below:

[image]

without involving cursor. Is that possible?

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is sufficient:

```
with n as (
      select row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 as n
      from master..spt_values
     )
select t.*, dateadd(day, n.n, t.startDate) as thedate
from t join
     n
     on dateadd(day, n.n, t.startDate) <= t.endDate;
```

Comment: Thank you, Gordon as always! But would you please elaborate on the recursive part? It works but I am a bit confused about "select row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 as n
      from master..spt_values".. Could you point me to some documentation of its usage?

Comment: @user1205746 . . . These is no recursive part.  I just use that formulation to get a list of a few hundred numbers.

Comment: oh! I see... is there a limitation of the numbers? I should say what is the max number?

Comment: @user1205746 . . . The size of the table.  I think there are at least 2,000 rows in it.