# Save data of a common table expression into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is an extension of my previous question:
[Auto generating dates based on a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42731159/auto-generating-dates-based-on-a-table)

I got the resolution which works perfectly

```
with n as (
      select row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 as n
      from master..spt_values
     )
select t.*, dateadd(day, n.n, t.startDate) as thedate
from t join
     n
     on dateadd(day, n.n, t.startDate) <= t.endDate;
```

However, I would like to make the result persistent by saving it into a table. Is it possible to persistent the data? I tried the **select into statement** but it did not work

The whole statement is:

```
select into ABC
(
    with n as (
          select row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 as n
          from master..spt_values
         )
    select t.*, dateadd(day, n.n, t.startDate) as thedate
    from t join
         n
         on dateadd(day, n.n, t.startDate) <= t.endDate
)
```

The error received was:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 146
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'into'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 148
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 168
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

How do I save the result into a table?

Comment: please post your complete query insert query is not there in this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice where the `into ABC` is

```
 ;with n as (
    select row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 as n
    from master..spt_values
)
select t.*
     , dateadd(day, n.n, t.startDate) as thedate
 into ABC
 from t join  n      
   on dateadd(day, n.n, t.startDate) <= t.endDate
```

Comment: Thank you John! It works!! Very much appreciated. One curious question what does the semi colon before with do (;with) ? I can get away without it.

Comment: @user1205746 I included the ; just in case you had statements prior to the cte

Comment: @user1205746 failed to mention ... Happy it helped  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
with n as (
          select row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 as n
          from master..spt_values
         )
with ABC as(
    select t.*, dateadd(day, n.n, t.startDate) as thedate
    from t join
         n
         on dateadd(day, n.n, t.startDate) <= t.endDate
)
```

Now you can use Abc in another query.

Comment: if you want to save these result you should use insert into query